# There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: Instance of Categorie

Tags: flutter, dart

hi I work to update value from DropdownButton.but I get this error:

**There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: Instance of 'Categorie'.
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value**

```
                     padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0, bottom: 10.0),
                     child: new DropdownButton<Categorie>(
                             hint: new Text("Selectionnez une catégorie"),
                             value: selectedCataId,
                             onChanged: (Categorie newValue) {
                               setState(() {
                                 selectedCataId = newValue;
                                 pAudit.categorie = selectedCataId;
                                 debugPrint('C selectedCataId: ' + selectedCataId.toString());
                                 debugPrint('C pAudit.categorieId: ' + pAudit.categorie.id.toString());
                               });
                             },
                             items: this.cataList.map((Categorie dropDownCataItem) {
                               return new DropdownMenuItem<Categorie>(
                                 value: dropDownCataItem,
                                 child: new Text(
                                  /* dropDownCataItem.abreviation*/  ' - ' + dropDownCataItem.label,
                                   style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                 ),
                               );
                             }).toList(),
                     ),
                   ),
```

Comment: Hi, can you show me whats in the cataList??

Comment: cataList contain list of Categorie

Comment: does it have any duplicate value? if so, its probably the problem..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DropdownButton` needs a list of items with **unique key** for each of them as the value. then DropdownButton would use these values (key) to distinguish different items. it seems that your `cataList` has one or more duplicate items. if so, you would have two solutions:

1. add a unique key parameter to each item in `cataList` and use it as a value, therefore you can have the same items in your dropdown (if you need so).
2. remove one the duplicate items!